# How to create a dependency between a Jar and a project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I made two projects P1 and P2 in eclipse IDE. P2 depends on P1. I did not create any dependency between P1 and P2. I want to convert P1 to Jar and then make P2 use that Jar.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export your project `P1` as `Jar`. Right click on project, go to *Export*, go to `Java`, select `Jar File`.

And then add that `Jar` to the `Build Path` of project `P2`. Right click on project, go to *Build Path*, go to *Configure Build Path* -> *Libraries* tab. Click *Add External JARs* button, and add the Jar.

See this blog: - http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html to learn various features of Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks ! I read the tutorial and did it. But, I have one question. I did not have to write any import statements. All the red crosses/problems just disappeared. Why did that happen ? What did eclipse do behind the scenes to make this happen ?

Comment: @AppleGrinder.. When you add a Jar file to the build path as external library, it is automatically referenced in your project from there. You don't need to import the classes from them.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. I don't see any import statements appearing in my P2 code. So, eclipse must have done something somewhere to make this work. What is that something and where does it happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Project dependency (but no jar dependency) : clight click on your P2 project to gets the properties. Go to Java Build Path, and choose Project, add your P1 project here. It will be added in the classpath of your P2 project.